# Apollo client with wsLink, authLink, httpLink and uploadLink

Tags: javascript, reactjs, graphql, graphql-js

I'm using nextjs (react) on my front end and I've setup graphql to accept an authlink, websocket link and http link which all works fine. I now need to also include an uploadLink to accept file uploads from the client, but I can't seem to get it to work. Any advice greatly appreciated!

Here is what I have so far that does work (wslink, authlink + httplink)

```
const wsLink =
    typeof window !== "undefined"
        ? new GraphQLWsLink(
            createClient({
                url: `ws://localhost:8001/graphql/subscriptions`,
                connectionParams: async () => ({
                    authorization: getCookie('token')
                }),
            })
        )
        : null;

const httpLink = new HttpLink({
    uri: `http://localhost:8001/graphql`,
    credentials: "include",
});

const authLink = setContext((_, { headers }) => {
    // const token = localStorage.getItem('token')
    const token = getCookie('token')
    return {
        headers: {
            ...headers,
            authorization: token
        }
    }
})

const link =
    typeof window !== "undefined" && wsLink != null
        ? split(
            ({ query }) => {
                const def = getMainDefinition(query);
                return (
                    def.kind === "OperationDefinition" &&
                    def.operation === "subscription"
                );
            },
            wsLink,
            authLink.concat(httpLink)
        )
        : authLink.concat(httpLink);

export const client = new ApolloClient({
    link,
    cache: new InMemoryCache(),
});
```

I've created the uploadLink with

```
let uploadLink = createUploadLink({
    uri: "http://localhost:8001/graphql"
})
```

And I've tried tacking it on in a few different ways such as

```
const link =
    typeof window !== "undefined" && wsLink != null
        ? split(
            ({ query }) => {
                const def = getMainDefinition(query);
                return (
                    def.kind === "OperationDefinition" &&
                    def.operation === "subscription"
                );
            },
            wsLink,
            uploadLink,
            authLink.concat(httpLink)
        )
        : authLink.concat(httpLink);
```

Not quite sure what I'm doing wrong though.